# excel VBA to open NanoCAD application

Tags: excel, vba, cad, nano

I wanted to try out automating multiple drawings generation in NanoCAD. there are many sources to help with AutoCAD, but not much with NanoCAD. 
for Example, can some one give me a equivalent code for below (which we can use to open Autocad) to open NanoCAD ?

I have the references to the NanoCAD commands done properly. like we do for Autocad.

```
Sub opencad()
    Dim ACAD As AcadApplication 'Create ACAD variable of type AcadApplication
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set ACAD = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application") 
    On Error GoTo 0 
    If ACAD Is Nothing Then 
        Set ACAD = New AcadApplication 
        ACAD.Visible = True 
    End If
    ACAD.ActiveDocument.Utility.Prompt "ZOOM ALL " 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use such code:

```
Dim app As nanoCAD.Application
Set app = GetObject("", "nanoCAD.Application")
```

Also don't forget to include nanoCAD type lib (NCAuto.dll) into your project (menu Tools - Reference..)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much vlalexey! I need to explore many of the commands I need!

Comment: Can you recommend a book or a website to get to know the VBA commands for NanoCAD?

Comment: 99% of the vba code is the same
in VBA fo autocAD you can use this `dim intA as Integer`
in VBScript for NanoCAD you type don't have to be declared `dim intA`
in the for cycle don't put c at the end line `next c`
`for c = 1 to 10
     . . . 
     . . . 
next c`
`Debug.print` become `ThisDrawing.Utility.Prompt "bla bla bla"`

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while before I could finally find a CMS IntelliCAD software that is as good and easy to use as AutoCAD. What I appreciated most is that I can easily edit my .dwg files and it basically offers all features that I’m used to working with. Since CMS IntelliCAD gave me a free trial option, I tried to work with other software as well, including freeware, to compare and understand which one worked for me better. Out of everything I’ve tried so far, CMS IntelliCAD is definitely the best one in all aspects. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

The best part of using CMS IntelliCAD was finding out it has all the CAD features I’d already worked with. I was pretty worried about finding a good fit for me, but CMS IntelliCAD is definitely unbeatable. Registered for free and had a free trial before payment, I'm glad I could test it out before any payment. CMS IntelliCAD is definitely worth the hype.

Comment: A similar answer has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a hobbyist looking for a CAD software that's easy to use and powerful, look no further than CADHOBBY IntelliCAD. It's the perfect software for creating 3D designs and models.